# Kernel ridge regression and Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, ridge-regression

One knows that through the both methods mentioned in the title, in regression setting, with the same kernel $K$, the result is the same.
It may be a very naive question but why?
To me, they are quite different approaches but I guess there are some underlying connections which explain the same result.